# What application (and options) should I use to get terminal access to my Raspberry Pi over a USB/serial cable on Linux?

Tags: raspbian, debian, linux, serial

I've got a Raspberry Pi with a [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) SD card, connected to my [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) laptop via a [USB TTY cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/954). The cable is supplying power to the board; my user is in the `dialout` group, and can see `/dev/ttyUSB0`. What application should I use to obtain terminal access to my Raspberry Pi via this serial port?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Occidentalis](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2) distribution, and it has the following lines at the end of `/etc/inittab`:

```
#Spawn a getty on Raspberry Pi serial line
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

Once you have this you should be able to use a terminal emulator like [Minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) on your Debian laptop to connect to the Raspberry Pi, and you will get a login prompt. Make sure the port speed on the laptop matches the settings on the Raspberry Pi (115200 bits/s in the example above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any terminal emulator such as `PuTTY`. You can even do a simple test with `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` and try typing stuff in there...

However, there must be something running at the other end, such as `getty` for you to be able to login. I believe this might be activated by default on `ttyAMA0`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/inittab to spawn serial consoles.

I like to use the [Minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) client on the other end, rather than [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).